# jQuery slide toggle animation makes other elements jumpy when resizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So I'm trying to animate a sidebar sliding in from the left, and the animation works well but it makes the other element, which uses flex for sizing, jumpy while it automatically resizes. This is what it looks like: 
[image]

Here's some of my CSS:

```
body{
display: flex;
}

#sidebar{
display: none;
float: left;
height: 100%;
position: relative;
padding-left: 20px;
padding-right: 20px;
}

#mainScreen{
float: right;
height: 100%;
flex-grow: 1;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
}
```

And here's my basic HTML structure:

```
<body>
<div id="sidebar>
<!-- stuff -->
</div>
<div id="mainScreen">
<div id="headerCont"><!-- stuff --></div>
<div id="messageCont"><!-- stuff --></div>
<div id="chatInputCont"><!-- stuff --></div>
</div>
</body>
```

And the children of #mainScreen have another flex arrangement, but vertically. In Javascript I'm using `$("#sidebar").toggle("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);`  when you click the menu button and it nearly works but I just want to eliminate the jumpiness. Does any know how to fix this, or if there are any alternative approaches I haven't thought of?

Comment: Do you mind adding your html as well or better build a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can reproduce the problem

Comment: Added some HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its actually float creating problem, Its better restructure your HTML if Possible something like this.

```
<body>
 <div class="main-content>
   <div class="left-section">
     <div id="sidebar>
      <!-- stuff -->
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="right-section">
     <div id="mainScreen">
     <div id="headerCont"><!-- stuff --></div>
     <div id="messageCont"><!-- stuff --></div>
     <div id="chatInputCont"><!-- stuff --></div>
     </div>  
   </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

Now remove `float` and use `flex` on `.main-content`.

css

```
.left-section {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -100%;
}

.left-section.slide {
  left: 0;
}

.main-content.slide {
  margin-left: 188px; // left-sidebar width
}

function sidebarClick(){
  $(".left-section, .main-content").toggleClass("slide");
}
```

Comment: Thanks - it's an improvement but .right-section still doesn't resize smoothly with the animation as I'd like. [Looks like this](https://i.imgur.com/e9ysgrg.gif)

Comment: use slide function on `.left-section`. Hope will solve the problem.

Comment: Looks like my original screen gif again

Comment: can you share your live site somewhere?

Comment: I created a JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/row101/1ctgwo4d/31), sorry I probably should have done that from the start

Comment: Required css and jquery has been updated above. Please check. Hope this will solve your prob. For the slow motion or smooth you can add transistion in css or apply animation by jqery or css as per your choice.

Comment: Awesome, it works how I wanted now with some transitions -- thank you so much your help :)